# How can the different core-icons iconsets be used in Dart?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, paper-elements, core-elements

core-icons contains different iconsets like

- icons
- av-icons
- communication-icons
- device-icons
- hardware-icons
- image-icons
- maps-icons
- notification-icons
- png-icons
- social-icons

It's not obvious how to use them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an overview of the icons contained in paper-elements http://polymer.github.io/core-icons/components/core-icons/demo.html

I created an example that demonstrates how to use them.

```dart
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>core-icons</title>
    <!-- <script src="packages/web_components/platform.js"></script>
         not necessary anymore with Polymer >= 0.14.0 -->
    <script src="packages/web_components/dart_support.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="packages/paper_elements/paper_icon_button.html">
    <!-- choose the name according to the set you want to load - "social-icons" -->
    <!-- this is now accessible with a simpler path
    <link rel="import" href="packages/core_elements/src/core-icons/iconsets/social-icons.html"> 
    <link rel="import" href="packages/core_elements/core_icons/iconsets/social_icons.html"> 
    this changed again with core-elements 0.2.0+1 -->
    <link rel="import" href="packages/core_elements/social_icons.html">
  </head>
  <body>

    <!-- use the icon by setting the `icon` attribute. The value consists of iconsset-id a colon followed by the icon name. -->
    <paper-icon-button id="bookmark-button" icon="social:plus-one" style="fill:steelblue;"></paper-icon-button>

    <script type="application/dart">export 'package:polymer/init.dart';</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

#### EDIT

You can style the icons from Dart code like

```dart
($['bookmark-button'] as dom.Element).querySelector('* /deep/ #icon').style
    ..setProperty('fill', 'red')
    ..setProperty('stroke', 'blue')
    ..setProperty('stroke-with', '3px');
```

This turned out to be quite a bit tricky because the `paper-icon-button` has more than one `shadowRoot` (3 actually) and when I set the style on the `<g>` element (inside the `<core-icon>`) it was applied but reverted shortly afterwards for unknown reasons.

I just saw that this doesn't work in Firefox. The polyfill for `/deep/` in `querySelector()` is work in Progress as far as I know. Maybe it will work better as soon as the current Polymer release has been integrated in Polymer.Dart.

This worked in both Dartium and Firefox:

```dart
($['bookmark-button'] as dom.Element).shadowRoot.olderShadowRoot.querySelector('#icon').style
    ..setProperty('fill', 'red')
    ..setProperty('stroke', 'blue')
    ..setProperty('stroke-with', '3px');
```

This solution might break when the implementation of `<paper-icon-button>` is changed but hopefully in a while the first attempt will work in all browsers soon.

### EDIT

Polyfill support for `/deep/` in `querySelector` is included in [Polymer.js 0.4.0](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/releases/tag/0.4.0). Hopefully the next Polymer.dart update includes it as well.

Comment: How can I set the | style="fill:steelblue;" | programatically given that I have retrieved the icon so $['bookmark-button']. |$['bookmark-button'].attributes[ 'style' ] = 'fill: green;';| does not work.

Comment: Thanks Gunter. I definitely would not have figured that one. It seem so simple when I started but it turned out to be anything but simple.

Comment: I remember how hard it was to figure out how this shadow-thingy works. I still don't know all details. Most of the time detailed knowledge isn't necessary anyway ;-)